# How to add a stop and start feature for an RxJS timer?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I added a start, stop, pause button. Start will start a count down timer which will start from a value, keep decrementing until value reaches 0. We can pause the timer on clicking the pause button. On click of Stop also timer observable completes.

- However, once the timer is completed ( either when value reaches 0 or
  when clicked on stop button ), I am not able to start properly. I
  tried adding repeatWhen operator. It starts on clicking twice. Not at
  the first time.
- Also, at stop, value is not resetting back to the initial value.

```js
const subscription = merge(
  startClick$.pipe(mapTo(true)),
  pauseBtn$.pipe(mapTo(false))
)
  .pipe(
    tap(val => {
      console.log(val);
    }),
    switchMap(val => (val ? interval(10).pipe(takeUntil(stopClick$)) : EMPTY)),
    mapTo(-1),
    scan((acc: number, curr: number) => acc + curr, startValue),
    takeWhile(val => val >= 0),
    repeatWhen(() => startClick$),
    startWith(startValue)
  )
  .subscribe(val => {
    counterDisplayHeader.innerHTML = val.toString();
  });
```

Stackblitz Code link is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tdcfxf?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty complicated usecase. There are two issues I think:

- You have two subscriptions to `startClick$` and the order of subscriptions matters in this case. When the chain completes `repeatWhen` is waiting for `startClick$` to emit. However, when you click the button the emission is first propagated into the first subscription inside `merge(...)` and does nothing because the chain has already completed. Only after that it resubscribes thanks to `repeatWhen` but you have to press the button again to trigger the `switchMap()` operator.
- When you use `repeatWhen()` it'll resubscribe every time the inner Observable emits so you want it to emit on `startClick$` but only once. At the same time you don't want it to complete so you need to use something like this:

  ```
  repeatWhen(notifier$ => notifier$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => startClick$.pipe(take(1))),
  )),
  ```

So to avoid all that I think you can just complete the chain using `takeUntil(stopClick$)` and then immediatelly resubscribe with `repeat()` to start over.

```
merge(
  startClick$.pipe(mapTo(true)),
  pauseBtn$.pipe(mapTo(false))
)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(val => (val ? interval(10) : EMPTY)),
    mapTo(-1),
    scan((acc: number, curr: number) => acc + curr, startValue),
    takeWhile(val => val >= 0),
    startWith(startValue),
    takeUntil(stopClick$),
    repeat(),
  )
  .subscribe(val => {
    counterDisplayHeader.innerHTML = val.toString();
  });
```

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tum4xq?file=index.ts

Comment: Thats a great explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example stopwatch that counts up instead of down. Perhaps you can re-tool it.

```ts
type StopwatchAction = "START" | "STOP" | "RESET" | "END";

function createStopwatch(
  control$: Observable<StopwatchAction>, 
  interval = 1000
): Observable<number>{

  return defer(() => {
    let toggle: boolean = false;
    let count: number = 0;

    const ticker = timer(0, interval).pipe(
      map(x => count++)
    );
    const end$ = of("END");

    return concat(
      control$,
      end$
    ).pipe(
      catchError(_ => end$),
      switchMap(control => {
        if(control === "START" && !toggle){
          toggle = true;
          return ticker;
        }else if(control === "STOP" && toggle){
          toggle = false;
          return EMPTY;
        }else if(control === "RESET"){
          count = 0;
          if(toggle){
            return ticker;
          }
        }
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
  });
}
```

Here's an example of this in use:

```ts
const start$: Observable<StopwatchAction> = fromEvent(startBtn, 'click').pipe(mapTo("START"));
const reset$: Observable<StopwatchAction> = fromEvent(resetBtn, 'click').pipe(mapTo("RESET"));

createStopwatch(merge(start$,reset$)).subscribe(seconds => {
  secondsField.innerHTML  = seconds % 60;
  minuitesField.innerHTML = Math.floor(seconds / 60) % 60;
  hoursField.innerHTML    = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in another way without completing the main observable or resubscribing to it using `takeUntil`, `repeatWhen`, or other operators, like the following:

- create a simple `state` to handle the `counter` changes (`count`, `isTicking`)
- `merge` all the observables that affecting the counter within one observable.
- create intermediate observable to interact with the main `merge` observable (start/stop counting).

```js
interface CounterStateModel {
  count: number;
  isTicking: boolean;
}

// Setup counter state
const initialCounterState: CounterStateModel = {
  count: startValue,
  isTicking: false
};

const patchCounterState = new Subject<Partial<CounterStateModel>>();
const counterCommands$ = merge(
  startClick$.pipe(mapTo({ isTicking: true })),
  pauseBtn$.pipe(mapTo({ isTicking: false })),
  stopClick$.pipe(mapTo({ ...initialCounterState })),
  patchCounterState.asObservable()
);

const counterState$: Observable<CounterStateModel> = counterCommands$.pipe(
  startWith(initialCounterState),
  scan(
    (counterState: CounterStateModel, command): CounterStateModel => ({
      ...counterState,
      ...command
    })
  ),
  shareReplay(1)
);

const isTicking$ = counterState$.pipe(
  map(state => state.isTicking),
  distinctUntilChanged()
);

const commandFromTick$ = isTicking$.pipe(
  switchMap(isTicking => (isTicking ? timer(0, 10) : NEVER)),
  withLatestFrom(counterState$, (_, counterState) => ({
    count: counterState.count
  })),
  tap(({ count }) => {
    if (count) {
      patchCounterState.next({ count: count - 1 });
    } else {
      patchCounterState.next({ ...initialCounterState });
    }
  })
);

const commandFromReset$ = stopClick$.pipe(mapTo({ ...initialCounterState }));

merge(commandFromTick$, commandFromReset$)
  .pipe(startWith(initialCounterState))
  .subscribe(
    state => (counterDisplayHeader.innerHTML = state.count.toString())
  );
```

Also here is the working version:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-o86zg5

Comment: Thank you. One part I don't prefer is  operator functions having an external dependency making those impure functions.